# Databag defined environment attributes used with a policyfile

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Using a policyfile, I'm trying to run a recipe that uses a databag to define environment specific settings.

I have the following databag item in a databag called "env":

```
{
    "id": "enviornment_local",
    "filename": "environment_local.json",
    "efs": {
        "database_mount": "fs-c2fa7d8b"
    }
}
```

I have the following defined in my recipe:

```
environment = data_bag_item('env', "environment_#{Chef::Config.policy_group}")
Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.hash_only_merge!(node.role_default, environment)

efs_database_mount = node['efs']['database_mount']
```

The attribute is not being picked up in this code here:

```
az = node['ec2']['placement_availability_zone']
region = az[0..-2] # trim last char
file_system_id = efs_database_mount #'fs-c2fa7d8b'
efs_uri = "#{az}.#{file_system_id}.efs.#{region}.amazonaws.com:/"
```

The error is:

```
   NoMethodError
   -------------
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the first think is the correct way to get the group name is probably `node.policy_group` unless you're on a very old version of Chef. The next issue is you may want to merge into `node.env_default` depending on how you want ordering to work. Given the way you wrote that code, I'm guessing you're familiar with my poise-hoist library, so look over the rest of that for examples.

That said, which line exactly is raising the exception? You can use `node.debug_value` to check how values are being set at each level:

```
require 'pp'
# For node['foo']['bar']
pp node.debug_value('foo', 'bar')
# Output
[["set_unless_enabled?", false],
 ["default", "attributes default"],
 ["env_default", :not_present],
 ["role_default", "role default"],
 ["force_default", :not_present],
 ["normal", "attributes normal"],
 ["override", "attr override"],
 ["role_override", "role override"],
 ["env_override", :not_present],
 ["force_override", :not_present],
 ["automatic", :not_present]]
```

Comment: efs_database_mount = node['efs']['database_mount'] raises the exception. I'm assuming you're saying I should try Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.hash_only_merge!(node.policy_group, environment) or Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.hash_only_merge!(node.env_default, environment)? Looks like I've appeared smarter than I am on this... I've been reading http://hedge-ops.com/policyfile-attributes/ - this is where I got the original values.

Comment: I don't seem to have anything defined... [["default", :not_present],
        ["env_default", :not_present],
        ["role_default", :not_present],
        ["force_default", :not_present],
        ["normal", :not_present],
        ["override", :not_present],
        ["role_override", :not_present],
        ["env_override", :not_present],
        ["force_override", :not_present],
        ["automatic", :not_present]] ... sorry for the crammed output... maybe I still don't get how I'm supposed to reply on this forum lol

Comment: Comments aren't formatted, please add the output to your question via an edit so it is readable.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do something super advanced rather than just using the data bag item normally? You are mucking with deeply internal APIs, which is fine if you know what you're doing and can deal with breakages but that doesn't sound like it is the case.

Comment: I was just hoping for a way to remove environment specific attributes from my policyfiles. I've got quite a few and it would be much cleaner and less error prone to not have to copy and paste them in to new policyfiles.

Comment: Look at the example of using a shared policy file in https://github.com/poise/yolover-example

Comment: Ok you're layout is confusing BUT I did finally try your poise-hoist cookbook with the databag example on your site https://yolover.poise.io/ - all I can say is thank you! That cookbook works like magic :)

Comment: I'll probably add an explicit data bag mode to Hoist in the future, but might not be until after Chef 13 hilarity dies down so a few months.

Comment: That sounds nice :) got a problem right now where java does not want to accept some of the data bag attributes.. not sure if that's a bug or not at this point...